# How to create overlapping histograms

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a small R script below that creates a graph.
This script only imports one .csv or .tsv file.
However, I need to adapt it in a way that it can import multiple .tsv files and create overlapping graphs (transparent histogram and line) with different colours.

```
df = read.csv("your_distribution.tsv", sep="\t")
```

```
lower_bound = 0.001
    upper_bound = 5
    df = df[df$Ks < upper_bound,]
    df = df[df$Ks > lower_bound,]
```

```
dff = aggregate(df$Ks, list(df$Family, df$Node), mean)
```

```
 ks = c(dff$x, -dff$x + lower_bound)
```

```
hist(ks, prob=TRUE, xlim=c(0, upper_bound), n=50)
    lines(density(ks), xlim=c(0, upper_bound))
```

I have tried this code but I only get one solid mon colour graph.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to provide transparent colours is package **scales**. In base R, you can then overlay transparent elements using the `add` parameter like so:

```
library(scales)

hist(rnorm(100), col = alpha(rgb(1, 0, 0), .5))
hist(rpois(100, 1), col = alpha(rgb(0, 1, 0), .5), add = TRUE)
```

If you're familiar with `ggplot` (or willing to get so), you can add the `alpha` argument to any geometry. For the case at hand, the `ggplot`extension **[ggridges](https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/articles/introduction.html)** might be worth a try, too.

Comment: Thanks for your guides. Could you also please guide where to add these parameters in my script?